# How to select elements from a 4D Array?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am very new to *Mathematica* (first time!) and I'm already having troubles with arrays. I basically have a 4D tensor, that is a matrix (call it `M`) which has for each entry another matrix. I want to select the elements of the nested matrices that are bigger than zero, but `Select[M, # > 0 &]` doesn't work. I suspect it is because I do not respect the dimensions. I am kind of lost.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post `M` here?

Comment: Do you want the result as a simple list or something more structured (nested lists) ?

Comment: @J.M., i cannot post the whole thing because each entry is an integral of two function multiplied together.

Comment: @andre, i need to make a matrix out of it

Comment: Then, can you at least post a smaller version of your `M`?

Comment: here is how it looks like, where the s and s' are the functions that i integrate. 

ex = Array[s[#1, #2] s'[#3, #4] &, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {1, 0, 1, 0}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = RandomInteger[{1, 42}, {3, 3, 3, 3}];
```

`Cases` will extract every element equal to 42 here. (There won't always be any for the random nature.)

```
Cases[m, i_Integer /; i == 42, Infinity]
```

With `Position` you can identify where these elements are.

```
Position[m, i_Integer /; i == 42, Infinity]
```

`Select` selects sublists (row of matrices in this case) with some property, whether for example they containt a matrix with `42`.

```
Select[m, MemberQ[Flatten[#], 42] &]
```

Comment: You can replace levelspec `Infinity` with `{4}` for the nature of your input.

Comment: "(There won't always be any for the random nature.)" - for reproducibility, look up `SeedRandom[]`.

Comment: @J.M. `BlockRandom[...]` for example, I know that. Chances are with that many elements there will be at least one 42. :)

Comment: yes!!! It worked! I think its just because its the first time i use this program and i dont know how and where to use the right functions. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @user, if you're searching for a specific number, then this also works: `Cases[m, 42, Infinity]` (similarly with `Position[]`).

Comment: What if I want to make a list of elements based on their position in the sublists? 
I would like to make a list of the elements that lie on the diagonal and those below it for each 4x4 matrix that forms my 4D tensor.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is a matrix of the origial dimensions retaining only the selectred values you could do something like this:

```
  Map[ If[# > 0, #, Null] & , m , {-1}]
```